# How to transfer worlds?

Tags: ps4, minecraft-legacy-console

I have a cousin who is too lazy to visit my house so I want to transfer my Minecraft PS4 World Save Data to her PS4 version of Minecraft. Is it possible? If it is, then tell me how to do it, because i'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Get the files from your PS4 onto a USB stick. Upload the files from your USB stick to the internet. Get your friend to download them onto another USB and then put those files on his PS4