# Can I transfer my son's PS4 game from his brother's account to his own?

Tags: ps4

When we bought the ps4, both boys were playing games bought on the original account.  Unfortunately, one of the brothers does not behave very well and the other one is fed up with being reprimanded for his brother's behaviour and, as they play more and more, there is competition for the console.  Also, they tend now to play different games so I would like to open another account and transfer the VR games we have purchased on the first account over to the new account and keep the boys separate.  Is this possible?  I've thought about buying another PS4 but I will have the same issue and I don't want to buy the games twice, especially since most games are only played by one child.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transfer worlds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269703/how-to-transfer-worlds)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.playstation.com/en-nz/get-help/help-library/store---transactions/playstation-store-information---pre-orders/why-you-can-t-transfer-playstation-store-purchases-to-another-ac/

You cannot transfer PS4 games between accounts. If you want the games split between two separate account, you will have to buy the games again unfortunately.